# JavaScript and Jquery: How can you call a jquery function from within a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a button in a form that when clicked sends a variable to a javascript
function.  When the variable equals "link" I want to call a jquery function called makeLink().

This is what I have:

```
function getText(change)
{
   if(change == "link")
   {
      //call jquery function called makeLink()

   }

}
```

And here is my jquery function that creates a modal pop up with a form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function makeLink() {
    if ($("#makeALinkModalPopup").is(":hidden")){
    $("#makeALinkModalPopup").fadeIn("slow");

     $("#backgroundPopup").css({  
        "height": document.documentElement.offsetHeight

      });

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({"opacity": "0.7"});
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow"); 

        }

    }


});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The function is not global - that's the reason you can't call it. It has nothing to do with jQuery other than the fact that it happens to be a jQuery "ready" handler that contains it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the document.ready wrapping to make makeLink available to the rest of the page

```
    function getText(change){
      if(change == "link") {
      //call jquery function 

        makeLink()

      }
    }


    function makeLink() {
      if ($("#makeALinkModalPopup").is(":hidden")){
        $("#makeALinkModalPopup").fadeIn("slow");

        $("#backgroundPopup").css({  
          "height": document.documentElement.offsetHeight

        });

        $("#backgroundPopup").css({"opacity": "0.7"});
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow"); 

      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I must be doing something else wrong because removing the document.ready wrapping does not do anything.  I will continue to research. Thanks.

Comment: Any message in the console? Can you make a jsfiddle.net for us?

Answer (score 1):

Move makeLink to the global scope and call it normally.  There are only JavaScript functions.  The distinction you are seeing is scope only.

[Read about scope here.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

As someone else said, remove the document.ready wrapping.  Your function need not be defined there, because it cannot be seen outside of document.ready.

Comment: Can you give me more details? Or an example.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define the function inside the document ready event, but on a separate file.

Then, where you have:

```
//call jquery function called makeLink()
```

Just put

```
makeLink()
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need the dom ready.

Just have

```
function makeLink() {
    if ($("#makeALinkModalPopup").is(":hidden")){
    $("#makeALinkModalPopup").fadeIn("slow");

     $("#backgroundPopup").css({  
        "height": document.documentElement.offsetHeight

      });

    $("#backgroundPopup").css({"opacity": "0.7"});
    $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow"); 

        }

    }
```

Just have

```
function getText(change)
{
   if(change == "link")
   {
      makeLink();

   }

}
```

If you wanted to use the function on the dom ready then you would need to do.

`$(document).ready(makeLink);` < I might be wrong in sytax but to be safe i know this works..

```
$(document.ready(function(){
// do what ever you want
//even call make link

makeLink();
}
```